# Galaxy note 10.1 reset s-note picture import preferences

Tags: photos, gallery, default-applications, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, s-note

When I tried to import a picture earlier I accidentally set the S-note picture import preference to Gallery. Before that I was given the choice to import from Astro etc. .

I tried to delete all s-note data/cache in the preferences, but I was unable to reset the picture import to the non default value. (It didn't even delete the Documents on the device, they were back after a reboot).

The reset to default values button in the Task manager is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

One has to delete the Gallery user settings get the choice for the Import back.